# PXE Server - UEFI - iSCSI

Tags: linux, iscsi, pxe-boot

I have an Ubuntu Server serving as an iSCSI Target.

If I use PXELinux or iPXE with the the normal UNDIONLY boot method, it works fine.  The problem shows up when PXE booting EFI boot images; I no longer can connect to the iSCSI Target.

Are there any good PXE servers which can handle iSCSI under EFI?  I'd prefer finding a solution avoiding iPXE if possible.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try [Serva 3.0.0](http://vercot.com/~serva/an/WindowsPXE1.html)

(I'm related to Serva development)